# how can i restrict a database user to only access top 100 records of a table

Tags: sql-server, database

Let's say I have a database named as `db1` and a table with 10000 records, and I have a user named `user1` in the database.

Then if `user1` enters a query in MS SQL server:

```
select * from tb1, then it should return only 100 records.
```

there is only option to grant read or write permission to whole table.

Comment: show what have you tired and what error have you got.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

I don't think there is any built-in database method for doing this.  Often, applications will "page" results.  Iff the application runs in`select * from tbl1`, then the *application* only fetches 100 rows.  Note:  There is no concept of "top rows" in SQL without an `order by` clause.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.

If you want to limit users to seeing only 100 rows, then you can use a view:

```
create view v_table as
   select top 100 t.* from tbl1 t;
```

Also note that without an `order by` clause, this might return different rows on different executions.